# making list of categorical columns with unique values greater than a specific number pandas

Tags: pandas, list

I have a DF with categorical, numeric and date columns. I want to make a list of all categorical columns that have unique values more than 2. So my df is something like this

```
 date_time1      date_time2     cat_col1    cat_col_2    num_col1   num_col2   cat_col3
 2020-10-08       2021-11-08       ABC         xyz          20         40        PQR
 19:09:21.884     15:18:26.864
 2020-10-08       2021-11-08       BCD         xyz          30         50        ABC     
 19:09:21.884     15:18:26.864
 2020-10-08       2021-11-08       ABC         yza          40         30        MNO
 19:09:21.884     15:18:26.864  
 2020-10-08       2021-11-08       CDE         xyz          10         80        CDE
 19:09:21.884     15:18:26.864
 2020-10-08       2021-11-08       BCD         xyz          20         70        MNO
 19:09:21.884     15:18:26.864
```

I want to now get a list of only categorical column names which have unique value counts more than 2. So in this case it should be

```
 mylist =['cat_col1', 'cat_col3']
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: `df.columns[df.dtypes == 'category']`

Comment: I only want the column name that has unique value count greater than 2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the columns just by the name:

```
[col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('cat_') and df[col].nunique() > 2]
```

Result:

```
['cat_col1', 'cat_col3']
```

If you want to select by type:

```
[col for col in df.select_dtypes(include='category').columns if df[col].nunique() > 2]
```

Comment: no, my column names are all beginning with different names. But I used your code and removed the first if condition and I ran it. But this way, I get all column names with unique value gt 2, not just cat columns. Even date time columns, which I dont want

Comment: @user18334254: see updated answer

Comment: why not just do `df.columns[df.nunique()>2]` why use for-loop?

Comment: @onyambu: I was under the impression that OP wants to only consider category type columns (but this is not the case), and you need to append `.tolist()` to get the list anyway

Comment: yes, I only want cat columns. I took your code and modified it as below, and it works
[col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype=="O" and df[col].nunique() > 2]

Comment: But still you will not need a for loop. eg `cols = df.select_dtypes(include='category').columns; cols[df[cols].unique()>2]`

Comment: I like the list comprehension more in this case, I think it's easier to read, but yes - you can do as well `df.columns[df.dtypes.eq('category') & df.nunique().gt(2)].tolist()`

Comment: both return an empty list when I run

Comment: both return an empty list when I run

Comment: obviously you don't have any columns of categorical type

Comment: no, I do. I get the desired output from this code: 
[col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype=="O" and df[col].nunique() > 2]

Comment: that just means that you have strings, not categories! see [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) for an explanation what categoricals are.